# Rcpp: segfault on arrays > 698152 if IntegerVector is declared

Tags: c++, r, segmentation-fault, rcpp

I am running into what is probably a memory issue with c++ code interfaced with Rcpp. I could come up with the following minimal test case:

test.R:

```
require(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("test.cpp")
N <- 698153
testCpp(N)
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]] 
void testCpp(int N) {
    double closestLandmarks[N];
    int closestLandmarksIdx[N];
    IntegerVector l(10);
    // Fill the double and int vectors
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        closestLandmarks[j] = 1;
        closestLandmarksIdx[j] = 2;
    } // j

    return;
}
```

Running `Rscript test.R` results in a stack overflow: `Error: segfault from C stack overflow`. Basically, this code allocates two arrays of size N (it doesn't matter if they are int or double, they'll crash the same way), instanciates an IntegerVector of size 10, and fills first 2 positions of the arrays. I can basically remove any line here and it won't crash. It also won't crash with N < 698153 (this critical number varies a bit from machine to machine... 500000 seems always safe, while 1e6 crashes everywhere). It will crash if I iterate only until j < 2 instead of j < N, that is when it tries filling the 2nd position of the arrays.

I don't quite get why I should run into memory issues with 2 arrays I'd consider rather small (< 106) and a very small IntegerVector. My machine has plenty of free RAM (5GB out of 24GB) and I can use much, much bigger vectors / matrices in R without any issue.

I'm obviously missing something very stupid here. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You're not running out of memory, you have a _stack overflow_! (pun :p) BTW code like `double closestLandmarks[N];` (where `N` is a variable) shouldn't even compile (or at least it should give a warning!), it's a _variable-length array_ and it's C99 and not standard C++

Comment: We may even want to remove the 'rcpp' and 'r' tags -- it's "just" a C++ question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
double closestLandmarks[N];
int closestLandmarksIdx[N];
```

are both allocated onto the stack. For big N the stack will overflow, meaning that there is to little space on the stack.

You could allocate the objects on heap. `std::vector` will do that for you.
I would suggest:

```
std::vector<double> closestLandmarks(N);
std::vector<int> closestLandmarksIdx(N);
```

This is a interesting link to read, teaching you the difference between stack and heap:
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/

Comment: I knew I was missing something very stupid. Thanks for the link, it's very helpful as well.

Answer (score 6):

You are running out of stackspace. There is only so much memory given for stack (which is where local variables are stored). You need to use dynamic allocation:

```
double *closestLandmarks = new double[N];
int *closestLandmarksIdx = new int[N];

... 

delete [] closestLandmarks;
delete [] closestLandmarksIdx;
```

(Or use vector, as suggested in the other answer).